# react infinite scroll cant read all data

Tags: reactjs, infinite-scroll

my react-infinite-scroll can't read all my data in jsmart.sql, it comes 6 pack infinite repeating, how should i fix it?

react code: https://github.com/shihchinghuang/react-infinity-scroll

node code(including the sql file called jsmart.sql): https://github.com/shihchinghuang/MFEE14-final-project-server-shinder

Looking for help... thanks a lot